# How to extract a subfolder name with a particular pattern?

Tags: linux, path, find

I have a problem to extract a subfolder name with a particular pattern. For example,

```
/home/usr/VIP_00011_selected/Mark/Test
/home/usr/VIP_00021_selected/Mark/Test
/home/usr/VIP_02015_selected/Mark/Test
...
```

I would like to use 'find' or other commands to extract the subfolder names without '_selected', and the outputs like

```
VIP_00011
VIP_00021
VIP_02015
```

Thanks a lot. A.

Edit:

```
find . -type d -iname "VIP*"
```

can do partly of the work that returns

```
./VIP_02015_selected
```

But I don't want to return with ./ and I don't want _selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cut`:

```
$> find . -type d -iname "VIP*"
./VIP_00021_selected
./VIP_00025_selected
./VIP_00011_selected

$> find . -type d -iname "VIP*" | cut -d'/' -f2 | cut -d'_' -f1,2
VIP_00021
VIP_00025
VIP_00011
```

With `-d` you specify the delimiter, with `-f` which fields you want to print. In the first pipe, you cut with the `/` and select the second field (`VIP_00021_selected`), in the second, you cut through the `_` and keep the 1st and 2nd field (`VIP` and `00021`).

You can also specify a range of field: `-f1-3` will keep the 1st, 2nd and 3rd field. And you can combine: `-f1-3,5-10` will keep from 1 to 10 except the 4th.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. Could you please explain a little bit what is cut -f2?